# Create a list of numpy matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to make a list of numpy.matrix types

```
        n_dimension = list_CMTS[0].T.shape[0] - 1
        # define a list of UniD
        Sygma_UniD = [[]] * n_dimension

        for cmts in list_CMTS:
            annotation = cmts[-1, 0]
            mts = cmts[1:-1, 1:]
            for i in range(0, n_dimension):
                Sygma_UniD[i] = numpy.vstack( mts[0:, i] )
                # Sygma_UniD[i].append(mts[0:, i])
```

In this example I am trying to retrieve each column of index i in each mts and place it at the same index in Sygma_UniD. The problem is that I am getting some errors and redundancies.

How can I create a list of multiple numpy.matrix types ?!

Comment: not a solution, but may I recommend that you try to have a single function that _only_ receives `cmts`? Once you have that, you can just do `[get_matrix(cmt) for cmt in list_CMTS]`. Writing modularized code is always good

Comment: Have you tried `mts.T.tolist()`?  Or `list(mts.T)`.

Comment: the problem is how to extrac the data from matrix and convert it into a list